# More compact way to write onChange handler for form with many inputs that affect nested state properties?

Tags: reactjs

What is a more compact and more easy way to write a handleChange function for multiple input than the following:

```
import React from "react";

function initialState() {
  return ({
    customer: {
      name: '',
      primaryContactPerson: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
      }
    }
  })
}

export default class AddCustomerForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState();

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, field) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    switch(event.target.name) {
      case 'customer.name':
        console.log(1);
        this.setState({
          this: {
            customer: {
              name: event.target.value
            }
          }
        })
        break;
      case 'customer.primaryContactPerson.name':
        console.log(2);
        this.setState({
          this: {
            customer: {
              primaryContactPerson: {
                name: event.target.value
              }
            }
          }
        })
        break;
      case 'customer.primaryContactPerson.email':
        this.setState({
          this: {
            customer: {
              primaryContactPerson: {
                email: event.target.value
              }
            }
          }
        })
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='section section--full-width'>
        <h1>Add Customer</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className='form__row'>
            <label>
              Customer name
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="customer.name" value={this.state.customer.Name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className='form__row'>
            <label>
              Contact person
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="customer.primaryContactPerson.name" value={this.state.customer.primaryContactPerson.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
          <div className='form__row'>
            <label>
              Contact details
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="customer.primaryContactPerson.email" value={this.state.customer.primaryContactPerson.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>            
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the following method that does not work for nested objects:

```
handleChange(event, field) {
    this.SetState({event.targetname: event.target.value})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One dirty hack is using lodash `_.set`  [Link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#set). This is not the recommended method only a workaround.

you can use

```
const tmp = this.state;
_.set(tmp, event.target.name, event.target.value);
this.setState({ customer: tmp.customer });
```

if you want to avoid direct state mutation you can also use

```
const tmp = _.cloneDeep(this.state)
```

this process will be **slower**.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I was about to suggest set.  :)
I wouldn't consider it a hack either.  We use it in our form library to handle this exact case.

Comment: Thank you. Can you expand on what would be the recommended way? Is it to flatten my state? It is to use an immutability helper or Redux?

Comment: Another follow up question. What is the advantage of assigning state to tmp if state is mutated anyway by reference?

Comment: That is basically to show the intermediate _.cloneDeep method

Comment: I don't nest my states too deep, then state update becomes easier. Also i mostly use redux-form in my use cases, you can also have a look.

Comment: For any readers information: I decided to try to unnest my component states.